# Laravel 9 Uploads files to the wrong public folder

Tags: php, laravel

So, i have a folder in "**public**" where uploaded files goes to.
On server i have the project outside the **public_html** folder and only the index there.
Already modified the paths to point to the **public_html **folder.
Unfortunally, when i try to upload a file, instead of that file goes to the **public_html** folder.
Laravel creates a public folder and uploads the files to instead.

When i echoed the `public_path()` it pointed to where the project is and the public folder inside it instead of pointing to the public_html folder.

Here's the code:

```
function saveImageWithName($name,$photo,$folder)
    {
        $file_extension = $photo -> getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name = $name . '.' . $file_extension;
        $path = $folder;
        $this->removeImage($path . $file_name);
        $photo -> move($path,$file_name);
        return $file_name;
    }

    function removeImage($path)
    {
        if (!File::exists($path))
            return true;
        return File::delete($path);
    }
```

Note: i know about the storage. But i need to upload the files to the public folder it self. The one that is public_html.

Not2: .env file. if its on both local or production the same problem happens.

Note3: I Also tried chmoed the folder to 777 and it also didnt fix it.

Note4: The php code above works on other projects with the same php version and laravel version. This is just the first time im facing this problem.

Comment: I would probably suggest creating a [file storage/disk](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem) for public_html

Comment: I do know about the storage. But for this current project i had to use public.

Comment: Firstly, you're only showing half of the information in your question. What is `$name`, `$photo` and `$folder`? Secondly, for all we know, that code is playing around with relative paths. Thirdly, I don't see any laravel-specific functionality.

My suggestion is to: First, make sure your paths are all absolute. This is a golden rule in PHP coding. Never assume relative paths. Secondly, attach a debugger or do some print_r/dd's until you get your paths right.

Comment: "Firstly, you're only showing half of the information in your question." actually this is everything. This is where  i managed to traced the problem at.

Comment: What is $name, $photo and $folder? These are params.

Comment: Also, i did echo the public path and it showed the wrong the path as i mentioned above. anyway i managed to find a workaround for this problem. But still have no idea what triggered this problem to begin with. As a note: this is not my first project using laravel but this is my first time facing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i managed to do a workaround. Since, all the suggestions didnt work at all for me.
Although i still dont know exactly what or why this problem even happened.

So what i have done is as following:

in index.php file:

```
Define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
```

and in my class that handles uploading and storing file i just added ROOT_DIR before the path.

and it works currently very well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use public_path () function, you should use url ()

public_path ('public_html/a.jpg') returns the storage path, for example:
`C:\webroot\project\public\public_html`

Url ('public_html/a.jpg') returns the access address, for example:
`http://example.com/public_html/a.jpg`

But I suggest you use filesystem, which can also use public directories instead of storage.

```
// laravelProject\config\filesystems.php
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'public_html' => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => public_path('public_html'),     // Pay attention here
        'url'        => env('APP_URL').'/public_html',  
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw'      => false,
    ],

    ...
```

If you rename the public directory to public_html, you need to redefine and override the public function

```
// in your function file
function public_path($path = ''){
    return base_path('public_html/' . ltrim($path, '/'));
}
```